# How to duplicate a control in codeBehind C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to duplicate a control in an asp.net code-behind.

In my code:

```
HtmlGenericControl divRowHeader = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
divRowHeader.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Width, "323px");
divRowHeader.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.MarginTop, "2px");
divRowHeader.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.MarginLeft, "45px");
divRowHeader.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Height, "30px");
divRowHeader.Style.Add("border-top", "solid 3px lightgray");
divRowHeader.Style.Add("border-bottom", "solid 3px lightgray");
divRowHeader.Style.Add("border-right", "solid 3px lightgray");
divRowHeader.Style.Add("border-left", "solid 3px lightgray");

divTabRessources.Controls.Add(divRowHeader);
divTabInterim.Controls.Add(divRowHeader);
```

I want to add the same control to 2 different divs, but right now it just moves the control. Is there a function that duplicates a control and gives it another unique ID so there are no conflicts?

Comment: Learn how to write methods in C#. Factorize the creation of the div in a method.

Comment: This question has been asked and answered before. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161474/how-do-you-clone-webcontrols-in-c-sharp-net

Comment: That's a very ugly way of adding HTML to a page... there's no advantage sing codebehind in this case, you could simply put it in your aspx/ascx page... and if possible with no inline JS.

Comment: By factorize, he means take the parts of your code that can be reused and create a function that you can call. The function could return an `HTMLGenericControl`. All you'd need to do is modify the ID and add it to the div and you'd be good to go.

Comment: @mason is right, checks it answer. This is what I meant

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a C# method to do this, have a look at the `WebControl.MemberwiseClone()` method. Here are the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this method.

My suggestion, however, is to try to use a `Repeater` control. Here are the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this control.

Answer (score 1):

In response to your question about how to "factorize". You simply create a method from the code you attempt to reuse. Visual Studio does a good job of making it simple. It can basically do most of the work for you. Highlight the code you want to move into a method, right click it, then go to Refactor, then Extract Method. Give it a name and it'll create a function for you. Make your adjustments and you're good to go. Here's what the completed version might look like:

```
protected HtmlGenericControl CreateDivRowHeader(string id)
{
    HtmlGenericControl divRowHeader = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
    divRowHeader.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Width, "323px");
    divRowHeader.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.MarginTop, "2px");
    divRowHeader.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.MarginLeft, "45px");
    divRowHeader.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Height, "30px");
    divRowHeader.Style.Add("border-top", "solid 3px lightgray");
    divRowHeader.Style.Add("border-bottom", "solid 3px lightgray");
    divRowHeader.Style.Add("border-right", "solid 3px lightgray");
    divRowHeader.Style.Add("border-left", "solid 3px lightgray");
    divRowHeader.ID=id;
    return divRowHeader;
}

//now you can reuse the code
divTabRessources.Controls.Add(CreateDivRowHeader("control1"));
divTabInterim.Controls.Add(CreateDivRowHeader("control2"));
```

Comment: I'm don't think specifying the ID is required. If you don't, .Net will assign a generic Id (ctl0, ctl1, ...)